# iTextSharp to generate a gridview in pdf

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gridview, itext

I'm trying to export a gridview to pdf with package iTextSharp.

I'm doing it in my .aspx files :

```
<form id="formOptions" runat="server">

            [...]

            <asp:GridView ID="gvReportingStockComp" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" Visible="true">

                <Columns>

                    <asp:BoundField DataField="cod_wo" HeaderText="N° OF" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="composant" HeaderText="Composant" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="BESOIN" HeaderText="Besoin/OF" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="BESOIN_T" HeaderText="Besoin total" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="stock_dispo" HeaderText="Stock dispo" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="QTE_RESTANTE" HeaderText="Qte restante" />

                </Columns>

            </asp:GridView>


        </form>
```

And in my code behind, I fill the gridview :

```
OracleConnection oConnexion = new OracleConnection();
oConnexion.ConnectionString = "X";
oConnexion.Open();

string reqStockCompTotal = "intitulé de ma requete"

OracleCommand cmdReqStockComp = new OracleCommand(reqStockCompTotal);
cmdReqStockComp.Connection = oConnexion;
OracleDataReader readerReqStockComp = cmdReqStockComp.ExecuteReader();

gvReportingStockComp.DataSource = readerReqStockComp;
gvReportingStockComp.DataBind();

oConnexion.Close();
oConnexion.Dispose();
```

It work buit if I add the next code in order to make the export :

```
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=TestMES.pdf");
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);

StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);

gvReportingStockComp.RenderControl(hw);

StringReader sr = new StringReader(sw.ToString());

Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10f, 10f, 10f, 0f);
HTMLWorker htmlparser = new HTMLWorker(pdfDoc);
PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream);
pdfDoc.Open();
htmlparser.Parse(sr);
pdfDoc.Close();
Response.Write(pdfDoc);
Response.End();
```

In a first hand it block with :

```
gvReportingStockComp.RenderControl(hw);
```

and visual studio says : "GridView must be declared in  with runat=server"

Or it block to :

```
pdfDoc.Close();
```

and he says : pdfDoc is empty...

Somebody has an idea please ?

Answer (score 1):

Add below code to avoid runat="server" error.

```
public override void VerifyRenderingInServerForm(Control control)
{
    /* Verifies that the control is rendered */
}
```

You may want to disable paging so that it exports all rows of Gridview to PDF.

Add below code before gridview's rendercontrol method.

```
 gvReportingStockComp.AllowPaging = false;
 gvReportingStockComp.DataBind();
```

Incase you've any doubt, refer below article.

http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Export-GridView-To-Word-Excel-PDF-CSV-Formats-in-ASP.Net.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Add the `Rendering` Function after your PDF code

```
public override void VerifyRenderingInServerForm(Control control)
    {
        // verifies the control is rendered here
    }
```