# Error in converting aspx page to html (itextsharp 5.0.6)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, itext

I use this code to convert my aspx page to pdf using itextsharp 5.0.6:

```
 Using ms = New MemoryStream()

        Dim Html As String = vbCr & vbLf & "<h1>h1</h1>" & vbCr & vbLf & "<p class=""bo"">A paragraph</p>    " & vbCr & vbLf & "<ul> " & vbCr & vbLf & "<li>one</li>   " & vbCr & vbLf & "<li>two</li>   " & vbCr & vbLf & "<li>three</li>   " & vbCr & vbLf & "</ul>"
        Dim Html1 As String = RenderControlToString(Page)

        Dim styles As New StyleSheet()
        styles.LoadStyle("bo", "size", "10")
        styles.LoadTagStyle(HtmlTags.H1, HtmlTags.FONT, "59")
        styles.LoadTagStyle(HtmlTags.H1, HtmlTags.COLOR, "#ff0000")
        styles.LoadTagStyle(HtmlTags.UL, HtmlTags.INDENT, "10")
        styles.LoadTagStyle(HtmlTags.LI, HtmlTags.LEADING, "16")

        Using document As New Document(PageSize.A4, 10.0F, 10.0F, 100.0F, 0.0F)
            document.SetPageSize(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.A4.Rotate())

            PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, ms)
            document.Open()

            document.Add(New Paragraph("this is atest"))
            document.Add(New Paragraph("this is a test"))
            Dim strB As New StringBuilder(Html1)
            Using sReader As TextReader = New StringReader(Html1.ToString())
                Dim list As List(Of IElement) = HTMLWorker.ParseToList(sReader, styles)
                For Each elm As IElement In list
                    document.Add(elm)
                Next
            End Using


        End Using

    End Using
```

However I kept getting error on this line saying object reference not set to an instance of an object:

```
 Dim list As List(Of IElement) = HTMLWorker.ParseToList(sReader, styles)
```

If I changed from variable Html1 to Html in this line of code, it is working fine.

```
  Using sReader As TextReader = New StringReader(Html1.ToString())
```

Any idea how I can fix this error? Here is the function:

```
  Private Function RenderControlToString(control As Control) As String
    Dim sb As New StringBuilder()
    Dim sw As New StringWriter(sb)
    Dim writer As New HtmlTextWriter(sw)

    control.RenderControl(writer)
    Return sb.ToString()
End Function
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm guessing that `RenderControlToString` is returning null. I don't know specifically what that method does (the name is descriptive but I'd need to see the source) but there's a very good chance that you can solve this by overriding `VerifyRenderingInServerForm` on your page with an empty method. See this for a C# version: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17208338/231316

Comment: Thanks, Chris. I debug and I am sure the RenderControlToString is not null. I can see the string in the html. I have edited my post to include the function.

Comment: Does your rendered HTML have an `<hr>` in it by chance?

Comment: When you mentioned that, yes it does have <hr>. Is it the reason? Thanks

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/a/8576560/231316

Comment: Thanks, Chris. Since you mention the problem with <hr> and I removed it. Now it is working fine. I would love to vote up your answer but there is no place to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(comment moved to answer)

iTextSharp's `HTMLWorker` has known problems with `<hr>` tags. The short term solution is to just remove those tags but the long term solution is to switch to `XMLWorker` which supports those tags and is actively being developed and maintained.