# After intercepting Stream to change path of WebResource, Downloads fail

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

The problem is this code snippet James Law posted here: 
[Change the requested url of WebResource.axd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5536536/change-the-requested-url-of-webresource-axd)

If i intercept the Stream to change the path of WebResource ( and ScriptResource) all my Download links for Images and PDFs break. There is no Error, but the files the user downloads are broken. (PDFs are empty and Images not Viewable).

But i need to rewrite the url of WebResource or all my Ajax controls don't work when uploading to the server...

Could somebody explain why this is and maybe even how I could solve the problem? 
I have to admit as I am quite new to asp.net and the .net framework in general I don't really know what's going on in this code.

Comment: Please refer to the following answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17208227/itextsharp-to-generate-a-gridview-in-pdf/17208338#17208338